# Creating an anonymous object, how to use a loop to add items

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I'm currently creating a anonymous object like this, it works fine so far.

```
var users = new
{
   action = "users",
   newbies = new[]
   {
      new
      {
         email = "abc",
         username = "def",
         location = "ghi"
      }
   }
}
```

Now I need to modify this, by adding more properties to the inner object.
I have a List that has users in it, which represents the users friends.

```
List<User> friends = ...
```

So the inner object should look something like:

new

```
{
  email = "abc",
  username = "def",
  location = "ghi",
  friend1email = "f1@example.com",
  friend2username = "f1",
  friend2email = "f2@example.com",
  friend2username = "f2",
}
```

except I would need to get this using the LIst, so looping like:

```
foreach(var user in friends)
{

}
```

How can I generate this type of a anonymous object when I need to loop?

Note:  I can't change the format here, I know it is silly but that is how it is.

Update

**How can I do this using the ExpandoObject?**

Comment: Are you saying you want a dynamic number of `friendXemail` properties based on how many friends the associated list contains?

Comment: @DStanley yes that is what I am saying.

Comment: You should consider using a key value pair container like a `Dictionary`

Comment: @DStanley how about if I try the expando object?

Comment: It depends on what you want to _do_ with it - `ExpandoObject` does not have true "properties" - it just relies on `dynamic` to resolve them at run time.  So if you have code that expect properties (like mapping or serialization) it may not work,

Answer (score 3):

You could build up your object structure in JSON ( building a string is easy ), and then use a JSON deserializer (install NewtonSoft.JSON via NuGet) to convert it to an object.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with anonymous object but you can do it with `dynamic` object if you treat it as a dictionary.